# Rails label_tag do on helper only renders part of the content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our application we are showing inputs like so:

```
<%= f.label :date, class: 'field' do %>
  <span>Date</span>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
<% end %>
```

This is repeated very often so i decided to put it inside a helper like so:

```
def text_field_for(attribute, title, form, value = nil)
  form.label attribute, class: 'field' do
    content_tag(:span, title)
    form.text_field attribute, value: value
  end
end
```

However this is rending to html as following:

```
<label class="field" for="my_object_date">
  <input type="text" name="my_object[date]" id="my_object_date" />
</label>
```

Why its not rendering the span tag? I when i comment out the text_field it renders the span correctly. Somehow it is not able to render both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `concat` before both line in your method like below :

```
def text_field_for(attribute, title, form, value = nil)
  form.label attribute, class: 'field' do
    concat( content_tag(:span, title) )
    concat( form.text_field attribute, value: value )
  end
end
```

If you use concat it will join each HTML block generated in you label block.

Without it, i's only taking the last line as content. (Like a `return form.text_field attribute, value: value`)

Answer (score 0):

When you make your own helpers you need to use [concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) in order to add extra content to the block.

Something like this should work:

```
def text_field_for(attribute, title, form, value = nil)
  form.label attribute, class: 'field' do
    concat(content_tag(:span, title))
    concat(form.text_field attribute, value: value)
  end
end
```

Concat will add the content to the output buffer similar with how `<%= content %>` will do it in a template file.

If you later want to do something like this but you don't have a block, you need to use `capture` so that the content is captured and rendered to the page.

```
def another_helper
  capture do
    concat link_to("Star wars", star_wars_path)
    concat link_to("Star trek", star_trek_path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the last statement is returned from the block. You can combine the two using this:

```
form.label attribute, class: 'field' do
  content_tag(:span, title) + form.text_field(attribute, value: 'bar')
end
```

or

```
form.label attribute, class: 'field' do
  content_tag(:span, title).concat(form.text_field(attribute, value: 'bar'))
end
```